Blur fires after setting focus on newly added input element
Five years ago a question like what I will be asking today was asked but apparently no answers were posted that would solve the problem. Now I am having the same problem. Here is what I've done, so far.
    #cellHandlers = {
        lvCell: null,
        outerDiv: null,
        td: null,
        span: null,
        input: null,
        commitChanges: undefined,
        beginEdit: (td, cell) => {
            this.#cellHandlers.lvCell = cell;
            this.#cellHandlers.td = td;
            this.#cellHandlers.outerDiv = td.firstChild;
            this.#cellHandlers.span = td.querySelector('span');
            if (this.#cellHandlers.input == null) {
                this.#cellHandlers.input = document.createElement('input');
                this.#cellHandlers.input.type = 'text';
                //this.#cellHandlers.input.setAttribute('autofocus', 'true');
            }

            this.#cellHandlers.outerDiv.remove();
            this.#cellHandlers.td.appendChild(this.#cellHandlers.input);
            this.#cellHandlers.td.focus();
            this.#cellHandlers.input.select();
            // using setTimeout is a work around. The original code was
            //this.#cellHandlers.hookEvents(true);
            //this.#cellHandlers.input.focus();
            window.setTimeout(() => {
                this.#cellHandlers.hookEvents(true);
                this.#cellHandlers.input.focus();
            }, 10);
            //this.#cellHandlers.input.focus();
        },
        filterKey: e => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            const result = typeof this.#cellKeyFilter == 'function' &&
                this.#cellKeyFilter({
                    cell: this.#cellHandlers.cell,
                    key: e.key || e.data,
                    value: this.#cellHandlers.input.value,
                    pos: this.#cellHandlers.input.selectionStart
                });
            if (result)
                return true;
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        },
        hookEvents: a => {
            for (let h in this.#cellHandlers) {
                if (h[0] != '_')
                    continue;
                if (a)
                    this.#cellHandlers.input.addEventListener(h.substr(1), this.#cellHandlers[h])
                else
                    this.#cellHandlers.input.removeEventListener(h.substr(1), this.#cellHandlers[h])
            }
        },
        endEdit: e => {
            if (e !== undefined) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            }

            if (this.#cellHandlers.outerDiv) {
                this.#cellHandlers.hookEvents(false);
            }

            if (this.#cellHandlers.commitChanges) {
                this.#cellHandlers.commitChanges = false;
                if (this.#cellHandlers.span.textContent != this.#cellHandlers.input.value) {
                    this.#cellHandlers.span.textContent = this.#cellHandlers.input.value;
                    this.dispatchEvent(ListView.#evCellValueChanged);
                }
            }

            try {
                this.#cellHandlers.input.remove();
            }
            catch {

            }
            this.#cellHandlers.td.appendChild(this.#cellHandlers.outerDiv);
            this.#cellHandlers.outerDiv = null;
            this.focus();
        },
        _blur: e => {
            this.#cellHandlers.endEdit(e);
        },
        _input: e => {
            return this.#cellHandlers.filterKey(e);
        },
        _keydown: e => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            switch (e.key) {
                case 'Escape':
                    this.#cellHandlers.commitChanges = false;
                    this.#cellHandlers.endEdit();
                    break;
                case 'Tab':
                case 'Enter':
                    this.#cellHandlers.input.removeEventListener('blur', this.#cellHandlers._blur);
                    if (e.key == 'Tab') {
                        let index = this.#cellHandlers.lvCell.columnIndex + 1;
                        const cells = this.#cellHandlers.td.parentElement.cells;
                        if (index == cells.length)
                            index = 0;
                        this.#setActiveCell(cells[index]);
                    }
                    this.#cellHandlers.commitChanges = true;
                    this.#cellHandlers.endEdit();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

#cellHandlers is a property of a class that subclasses HTMLElement. It acts/mimics some capabilities of c#'s DataGridView. When a cell is clicked in this class and the cell's editable property is true, #cellHandlers.beginEdit is invoked where input element is created when it has not been created yet and added to the cell. The cell is a table cell (td) stored in #cellHandlers.td. Upon hooking up the events and setting focus on the input, blur event fires immediately and the handler of this event calls #cellHandlers.endEdit which, obviously end the editing state of the cell. Why such a behavior and how can I prevent it?
BTW, I hope no one suggests jQuery-ish solution although it could be a last resort.

Any chance you could [edit] your question into a runnable Stack Snippet with corresponding HTML?

The ListView class creates all its child elements on the fly when its connectedCallback() function is called. All you can do in the markup is very minimal: e. g. . You can insert some attributes and inline style to control its appearance. Everything else like adding items, adding headers is done through javascript. I am willing to share my code in its entirety but where?

How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

@Phil I'm afraid minimal is not an option. I have to post my entire class in order to post a reproducible example. The class does a lot of work inside connectedCallback: adding CSS rules, initializing the element itself and creating initial headers and cells. I need to post the entire class to post a minimal reproducible example.

No you don't. Just post enough to reproduce this particular problem. The best part about narrowing down your code is that you'll probably find the issue along the way.

I came here hoping to find a solution to the problem I asked but down votes were what I've got for whatever those mean. Anyway, I solved the problem myself. Thanks for the one and only one who spared time for me.

This is not actually a permanent solution. This is just a work-around that works for me and I will stick to it in the mean time.
After creating and adding the input element to the parent element I did this:
window.setTimeout(()=>input.focus(), 1);

Take note that autofocus attribute only works when the input element is newly created and not when the it is saved as node in a variable. So that work around for me is necessary.
Same is true when you remove the element and wants to give focus back to its parent element. I used the same logic.
Most of the time trial and error works (after screwing you up too much).

Wasn't this already handled by your 10ms timeout... this.#cellHandlers.input.focus()?

@Phil That's actually the problematic line because without setTimeout, blur fires immediately after calling focus on the input element and eventually the input never receives focus. Calling console.log(document.activeElement) shows that the body has the focus. And since the blur handler automatically removes the input element, no input element is ever shown.
